# Clone and replace attributes that are instances of a specific class

Tags: python

For a given object that may be an instance of a class, a built-in container or type, I would like to copy that object, but replace all instances of a given class with something else.  I can do this with two calls to `deepcopy` as shown below, but there may be a more straightforward approach.

Create some complex nested object:

```
class T(object):
    pass

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.t1 = T()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.y = 20
        self.t2 = T()

b = B()
```

Get a mapping from ids to objects:

```
visited = {}
copy.deepcopy(b, visited)
```

Create a custom dict type to replace instances of `T` with 100:

```
import collections

class Replacer(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, idmap):
        self.store = dict()
        self.idmap = idmap
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(self.idmap[key], T):
            return 100
        return self.store[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[key]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)
```

Copy and replace all `T` instances:

```
bb = copy.deepcopy(b, Replacer(visited))

In [121]: bb.t2
Out[121]: 100

In [122]: bb.a.t1
Out[122]: 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overly complicating what you are trying to achieve by defining your `Replacer` class. You need two passes because your logic is:

1. store each id of custom objects into `visited`, associated to a copy of it;
2. change the value associated to ids of `T` objects into `100`.

See how in 1. you already made a copy? You don't need that, you need to change how objects are copied in the first place.

The `deepcopy` function tries to copy a custom object `x` using one of 3 functions, in that order:

- `x.__deepcopy__`;
- `x.__reduce_ex__(2)`;
- `x.__reduce__()`.

`__reduce_ex__` and `__reduce__` are a bit special and provided by `object` by default so better not to touch it. `__deepcopy__`, however, is `copy.deepcopy` own mechanism and should be used anytime you want to change how `deepcopy` should create new objects out of old ones.

If all you want to do is to turn all `T`s into `100` when `deepcopy`ing an arbitrary object, then all you have to do is to implement `T.__deepcopy__` in such a way:

```
class T(object):
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo): # expected signature for copy.deepcopy
        return 100
```

Every `deepcopy` will then turn each `T` into `100`:

- Ex1:

  ```
  >>> b = [1,2,"hello",T(),('a',3,T()),T()]
  >>> copy.deepcopy(b)
  [1, 2, 'hello', 100, ('a', 3, 100), 100]
  ```
- Ex2, using your `A` and `B` classes:

  ```
  >>> b = B()
  >>> bb = copy.deepcopy(b)
  >>> bb.t2
  100
  >>> bb.a.t1
  100
  ```

Note that in the context of your implementation and various calls, the `T.__deepcopy__`'s `memo` parameter would be an alias to `visited`, use it as you see fit if you want to implement custom logic. Read the last paragraph of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for specific use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on what Mathias was saying, if I wanted to have some additional logic for how to replace instances of `T`, I could use a custom memo as follows.

```
class Replacer(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def replace_t(self, t):
        return t.idx * 100

class T(object):
    def __init__(self, idx):
        self.idx = idx
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return memo.replace_t(self)
```

Usage:

```
In [25]: b = B()

In [26]: bb = copy.deepcopy(b, Replacer())

In [27]: bb.t2
Out[27]: 200

In [28]: bb.a.t1
Out[28]: 100
```